# Executing a method everytime an item is added to a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

i want to execute a method each time an item is added to an DbSet.

Is this possible without calling this method seperate each time?

Comment: have you tired already some thing ?...

Comment: no, i have no approach, i don't know if this is even possible

Comment: Please clarify what is DbSet. If it is just a simple List<T> then inherit the List<T> and override the Add function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbSet has a property "`Local`" which is an `ObservableCollection`. You can subscribe to `CollectionChanged` on this to see when things have been added.

So something like:

```
this.ttActivities.Local.CollectionChanged += ttActivitiesChanged;


public void ttActivitiesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) 
{
  if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
  {
    // Something has been added
  }
}
```

Comment: i have `public DbSet<ttActivity> ttActivities { get; set; }` in my DbContext derived class. How can i add the event to it?

Comment: @zoidbergi I've updated my code sample, as you are deriving from DbContext you should be able to use this.ttActivities.Local.CollectionChanged to hook into the event.

Comment: unfortunately this event is fired when the ttActivites are created/loaded. is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: hmmm, good question; there is an OnModelCreating() method you could override on DbContext. Try hooking into your CollectionChanged event in there. I'm not near an IDE so can't test I'm afraid.

Comment: for me it turned out that i better override DbContext.SaveChanges. I should have mentioned in my initial question that i use EF